# How can i read the data with vertical bar pipe from txt file?

Tags: c++

How can i read the data  with vertical bar pipe from txt file? c++

```
    ifstream file_("user.txt");
    std::string id;
    std::string name;
    std::string section;
    int password;
    std::string address;
    std::string rank;
```

Comment: For instance `getline(file_, id, '|')` but you can't read integers that way. You have to read the integer as a string and then convert it to an integer,

Comment: just use getline instead of >>. I'll write an answer.

Comment: If you use C++, please do not add tag for C language. Its a different language.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (untested code)

```
ifstream file_("user.txt");
if (file_.is_open())
{
    string id;
    string name;
    string section;
    string password_s;
    string address;
    string rank;
    while (getline(file_, id, '|') &&
           getline(file_, name, '|') &&
           getline(file_, section, '|') &&
           getline(file_, password_s, '|') &&
           getline(file_, address)) {
         int password = stoi(password_s);
         cout << id << name << section << password << address << '\n';
    }
}
else
    cout << "file is not open" << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: if one line of datas is a1|People A|ABC|12345678|Flat A, Building 1, K.T                    and one line of datas is a2|People B|ABC|123456|Flat H, Building 2, H.K|member .                 the second line has more data , so how can i get 5 datas in line 1 and i get the 6 datas in line2???

Comment: @ivan You can fetch a whole line into a `std::string`, then iterate over the string and when you find a delimitor character (`|`) push the last word onto a `std::vector<string>`. Afterwards you can do whatever you want with it. For example handle all cases of the number of words in the vector.

Comment: @ivan The more complex your input requirements, the more work you have to do yourself. Hard to give specific advice since only you know the exact details of your input. But basically you have to analyse your input and take appropriate decisions depending on what you find.